# I had or I have

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

Wich one is correct?

1. Before that, I have completed two QQI Level 5 such as English, Business and IT as well as PC Specialist.
2. Before that, I had completed two QQI Level 5 such as English, Business and IT as well as PC Specialist.

Answer (score 2):

The use of "have" is incorrect here. The use of "had" can be grammatical, but it doesn't quite fit the context. Instead use: "**Before that, I completed....**". When listing your accomplishments, you want to be concise and use the most active voice possible.

Comment: Just to supplement this, you can use either "before that" or "I **have** completed", but not both the "have" and "before that".  "have completed" means that completion occurred in the past and is still applicable, so "have" conflicts with "before that".  "Had" refers only to the past, but if you are going to make the timeframe  more specific, you would typically tie it something specific rather than an unspecified amount of time prior to something else: "By the time XYZ happened, I had..." ties it to a specific time/event.